# Problems playing .mp4 files in Firefox on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: firefox, 17.10, mp4, html5

Currently .mp4 files do not stream properly in Firefox.

Can I check to see what file types are supported on my Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Can you play the same file in _Videos_ (totem)?

Comment: If possible give example url.  You could also browse here to check h.264 support. https://www.youtube.com/html5 (these days all 6 should be checked..

Answer (score -3):

firefox it doesnt decode media files, is just a graphic interface to the decoder(libav)

to see which codec you have installed on your pc open "synaptic package manager" > search for "codec"

ps: firefox is slow lately.. try chrome

```
apt-get update
apt-get install chromium
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, and it is not true.

Comment: @dobey - which part is not true may i ask

Comment: All of it really.  The first sentence is irrelevant (and possibly not true with firefox 57).

Comment: The second sentence advises to use tom tool which is not installed by default, and to search for something as some sort of clue, which may also be irrelevant to firefox, and so a pointless search. The correct way to list this would be to use an internal query in Firefox itself.

Comment: And lastly the "firefox is slow lately" is a lie, as 57 is much faster than previous Firefox versions. Also, telling people to just install a different browser, does not in any way answer the question about Firefox. Nor does simply using chromium instead even allow the file to be played. You have no idea what file won't play, and therefore if chromium would play it, even if the extra codecs package were installed.

Comment: how do you know is FF57? OP didnt specify; FF isnt a decoder its just a front end to the backend libavc; im on FF52 and its slow for sure

Comment: Because 57 is what is released into Ubuntu right now, as the latest security update. If you're on 52, you're using an unsupported version of Ubuntu, or installed Firefox from an unsupported source.

Comment: Any recent firefox can play .mp4 & .mov files if they contain h.264 vid & aac audio in the browser. (-  support is  built-in to firefox